# Powershell Winget/Choco Package updater script keeps reinstalling Microsoft.VCRedist.2015+.x64

Tags: powershell

```
# Set logfile path
$logFile = "C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Documents\\packageUpdater.log"

# Function to write output to a logfile and the console
Function WriteToLog($message) {
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value ("["+(Get-Date)+"] "+ $message)
    Write-Host $message
}

# Update packages via Winget
WriteToLog "Updating packages via Winget..."
try {
    $wingetOutput = winget upgrade --all 2>&1
    WriteToLog $wingetOutput
    WriteToLog "Winget update completed."
} catch {
    WriteToLog "An error occurred while updating Winget packages: $_"
}

# Update packages via Choco
WriteToLog "Updating packages via Choco..."
try {
    $chocoOutput = choco upgrade all -y 2>&1
    WriteToLog $chocoOutput
    WriteToLog "Choco update completed."
} catch {
    WriteToLog "An error occurred while updating Choco packages: $_"
}
```

When this script is run, it seems to install the `Microsoft.VCRedist.2015+.x64` winget package every time:

```
[07/16/2023 15:57:56] Updating packages via Winget...
[07/16/2023 15:58:03]    -\     -  Found Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) [Microsoft.VCRedist.2015+.x64] Version 14.36.32532.0 (1/1) Found Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) [Microsoft.VCRedist.2015+.x64] Version 14.36.32532.0 This application is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Downloading https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/eaab1f82-787d-4fd7-8c73-f782341a0c63/917C37D816488545B70AFFD77D6E486E4DD27E2ECE63F6BBAAF486B178B2B888/VC_redist.x64.exe    -\|/     ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆ  7.18 MB / 24.1 MB   ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆÔûÆ  17.1 MB / 24.1 MB   ÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûêÔûê  24.1 MB / 24.1 MB Successfully verified installer hash Starting package install...    -\|/-\  Successfully installed 
[07/16/2023 15:58:03] Winget update completed.
[07/16/2023 15:58:03] Updating packages via Choco...
[07/16/2023 15:58:06] Chocolatey v2.1.0 2 validations performed. 1 success(es), 1 warning(s), and 0 error(s).  Validation Warnings:  - A pending system reboot request has been detected, however, this is    being ignored due to the current Chocolatey configuration.  If you    want to halt when this occurs, then either set the global feature    using:      choco feature enable -name=exitOnRebootDetected    or pass the option --exit-when-reboot-detected.  Upgrading the following packages: all By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages. chocolatey v2.1.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s). openmw v0.47.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).  Chocolatey upgraded 0/2 packages.   See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
[07/16/2023 15:58:06] Choco update completed.
```

I am wondering why this is the case.